# OpenLayers 3.6.0 TouchEvents

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I can't seem to add event listeners for touch events. Only moveend gets fired.

```
map.on('zoomend', mapEvent);
map.on('moveend', mapEvent);
map.on('touchmove', mapEvent);
map.on('touchstart', mapEvent);
```

None of these work

```
map = new ol.Map({
        eventListeners: {

            "zoomend": mapEvent,
            "changelayer": mapEvent,
            "changebaselayer": mapEvent,
            "mousedown": mapEvent,
            "touchmove": mapEvent
        },
```

And this causing an error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined"

```
 map.events.register('touchmove', map, function(e) {
        console.log("touchmove")
     });
     map.events.register('touchend', map, function(e) {
         console.log("touchend")
     });
```

So now I'm totally lost!?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Do you want to know how to make the touch events work, in addition to what you did wrong? Or possibly an alternate method of integrating touch??

Answer (score 3):

That is exactly what is supposed to happen!

All those events you listed, besides `moveend`, don't exist on OpenLayers 3.6.0 anymore. Also, the config option *`eventListeners`* under `ol.Map` doesn't exist.
You can check all events and config options for `ol.Map` on the [official API docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html). The events are listed on *`Fires`* section.

Additionally, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqbm125c/1/) for some other events (`pointermove`, `pointerdrag`). On Chrome, you can also use Developer Tools (F12) to emulate a touch device and see what happens.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  controls: ol.control.defaults({
    attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
      collapsible: false
    })
  }),
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  })
});


map.on('moveend', function(e) {
    console.log("moveend")
});
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
    console.log("pointermove")
});
map.on('pointerdrag', function(e) {
    console.log("pointerdrag")
});
```